# correct inheritance in TS to avoid 'this' accessing value to early?

Tags: typescript, oop, design-patterns

Please see the following sample code:

```
abstract class BasicSystem {
    constructor(private basic: any) {
        this.bacicCall();
        this.extraCall();
    }
    private bacicCall() {
        this.basic.doThings();
    }
    protected abstract extraCall(): void;
}
class ExtraSystem extends BasicSystem {
    constructor(basic: any, private extra1: any, private extra2: any) {
        super(basic);
    }
    protected extraCall() {
        if (this.extra1.isGood) this.extra1.runSomething();
        else if (this.extra2.isGood) this.extra2.runSomethingElse();
        // 'this.extra1/2' here are obviously not going to work
        //  My question is:
        //  How do I write the correct pattern?
    }
}
```

One obvious way to 'fix' it is to NOT call the abstract function `this.extraCall()` in the base class. I understand TS base class haven't got the child class's private values at this stage. Leave that to the child class to call the `this.extraCall()` function later after `super(basic)` would 'fix' the problem, but that defeats the purpose especially if my base class code has more abstract functions & logics to run.

What is the correct design pattern to make a call to the abstract function in the base class, so that base class can call these abstract functions without having to worry how the children classes implement them?

Comment: Rule-of-thumb... It's not advisable to access `this` until your object is ***fully*** constructed. This means that doing abstract stuff on `this` from a constructor is ill-advised.

Comment: This is the reason that calling methods from constructors is generally an anti-pattern, especially if those methods can be overridden in subclasses. Constructors should *construct* things, not *do* things. Your best bet here is to refactor those calls out of the constructor.

Comment: In this specific case you could get around it by assigning `this.extra1` and `this.extra2` yourself _before_ calling `super`, rather than using parameter properties, but you'll also have to tell the compiler to ignore the possible error, which should tell you how bad an idea this is!

Comment: Would you please give an example on how to refactor my code here? Say, if I simply get each of the children implementation to call their own `extraCall()`, it that any better?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - And you'd have to not compile to ES2015+, because accessing `this` before `super` is an error in ES2015's `class` syntax. (But it does indeed work in ES5 function-based constructors.)

Comment: @Tom - I'd say that would be better, yes. Other ideas: 1. The [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) (but IMHO it can be a bit verbose to code). 2. Having `BasicSystem` pass additional constructor arguments (or perhaps all constructor arguments) to `extraCall`. 3. Accepting an object as the constructor parameter and saving the entire object to a property on `this` (like React components do with `props`). It really depends on the problem being solved. Happy coding!